# how to return a array in success block in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, objective-c-blocks

I'm getting data from a web service.then I want to put that data into a mutable array and return that arrary. I treid just to check the array is null or not.

I have define this in my header file

```
typedef void(^FailureBlock)(NSError *error);
typedef void(^SuccessBlock) (NSArray *responseArray);
```

this is my implementation file

```
- (void)setupConnectionWithsuccess:(SuccessBlock)success failure:(FailureBlock)failure
{
    airportArray = nil;
    NSString *Code = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"something"];
    NSString *authCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"something"];
    NSString *baseurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"someurl%@%@",authCode,Code];
//    NSString *mainurlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
//    NSURL *mainurl = [NSURL URLWithString:mainurlString];

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager GET:baseurl parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

        NSArray *mainArray = (NSArray *)responseObject;

        airportArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSDictionary *all in mainArray) {
            airports = [all objectForKey:@"port"];

            [airportArray addObject:airports];
            NSLog(@"%@", airports);
        }

        if(_successBlock){
            _successBlock(airportArray);
        }

        //NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
    }
    failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

        if (_failureBlock) {
            _failureBlock(error);
        }
        UIAlertController *mainAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Something Wrong!" message:[error localizedDescription] preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        [self presentViewController:mainAlert animated:YES completion:nil];

    }];




}

- (void)printap
{   NSLog(@"ffffuuu");
    [self setupConnectionWithsuccess:^(NSArray *responseArray) {

        NSLog(@"Checking ::::%@", responseArray);

    } failure:^(NSError *error) {

        UIAlertController *failureAlert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Errrrr..." message:@"Errrrr...." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        [self presentViewController:failureAlert animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
    NSLog(@"fkjfkdjkfjdkfjdk");
}
```

** I want to use this airportArray after data retrieved(want to return array). how can I do that

Comment: What issue are you having with the posted code?

Comment: inside the printapp `ffffuuu` and `fkjfkdjkfjdkfjdk` prints. but not going to success block or failure block.is there anything wrong with this. actually what I want is to return airportArray after data added to it

Comment: Use the debugger and see what happens inside the `setupConnectionWithSuccess:failure:` method.

Comment: it prints aiprort(successfully get value from the service and print).array is not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines:

```
    if(_successBlock){
        _successBlock(airportArray);
    }
```

should be:

```
    if(success){
        success(airportArray);
    }
```

I don't know what `_successBlock` is but you want to use the parameter passed into the `setupConnectionWithsuccess:failure:` method.

Make a similar change for the failure block by replacing `_failureBlock` with `failure`.

Comment: but how can I return that array.

Comment: You are returning the array by passing it to the completion block.